Delocalized electrons in the structure of graphite
It is mentioned in my chemistry book and on some online websites that the delocalised electrons present between the layers in graphite contribute to some sort of bonding? Supposedly, in order to make the overall structure stronger. Could anybody kindly explain this bonding that occurs and where does it specifically occur and how does it influence the strength of graphite?

Ever heard of double bonds? Also, the thing called $sp^2$?

Mhm, I have
However, after a bit of googling, it mentions online that the delocalized electrons are  somewhere middle in being delocalized and present in a double bond. Can you please explain this point? I think my concern lies over here. @IvanNeretin

Take a molecule like methane, carbon has 4 valence electrons and so forms 4 single bonds where it shares 4 electrons. Equally, ethene where carbon has 4 valence electrons and forms 2 single bonds and 2 double bonds. In graphite, it is in C-C
bonds in layers where carbon forms 3 single bonds. This means it has 1 electron left and so that leaves an electron in the bonding level. The spare electron in each carbon atom become delocalized over the whole of the sheet of atoms in one layer. (all p orbitals are orthagonal and so allign to form pi bonds but these pi bonds are localized to two specific atoms, it is stretched across entire molecule like a layer of double bonding. They aren't associated with a single carbon atom anymore hence delocalized. This makes it stronger because it is already strong from strong covalent bonds which you would have to break to break graphite. Unlike diamond however, the delocalized electrons also add additional bonding making it stronger.
In graphite carbon is sp2 hybridized meaning it forms 3 bonds with sp2 electrons and then has 1 electron left in p orbital. These p orbitals together come to form delocalized pi system.

What kind of measurement shows that graphite is stronger than diamond?

The bonds in graphite layer are stronger. There are also multiple source quotes on this like chemistrylibretexts. However it doesn't give a direct measurement. I would assume enthalpy of bonds in layers but I cannot be sure. A google search isn't helpful

Thank you for explaining the structure of graphite as concisely as possible however my doubt lay in the fact that this electron seemingly contributes to "stronger" bonding, but how does it do it? @user155568

In processes called resonance stabilization, delocalized layers stabilize the molecule therefore increasing bond strength. A great place to understand would be benzene. I have also slightly changed my answer for accuracy

@user155568 Sorry for the late response, Thanks a lot for the clarification. Yeah, I am a high school student and we haven't really studied resonance stabilization, but online searches have given me a sort of idea which clears my doubt. Thanks a lot again.
